# How to compare date in Groovy?

Tags: groovy, soapui

I need to compare two data in  format `13.07.2017 14:03:51,469000000` using groovy

I try to do this, but get error message.

I get next data:

time1 = `13.07.2017 14:03:51,469000000`

time2 = `13.07.2017 14:03:52,069000000`

Then I try to compare it:

```
time1  = time1['TIME'] as String
time2  = time2['TIME'] as String
assert time1 > time2, 'Error'
```

Which type of value should I choose for date for compare it?
Whats wrong in my comparing?

Comment: Are those two dates? how do you get that data? a screen shot?

Comment: I get two data values using SQL.

Comment: You need to post more information and/or exactly what your full code is. 
Also try printing out time1 and time2 before you compare them. Make sure they are exactly what you expect them to be before asserting on them.

Comment: Did it. I get data in format that you can see in description.

Comment: @Happy, please check the solution to see if that helps.

Comment: Date formatted as string in such national convention cannot be correct. Never compare date as string

Comment: @Happy, have you got chance to check the solution?

Answer (score 8):

You need to convert the string to Date and then compare as shown below.

In order to convert, the right date format should be used.

Here you go, comments inline:

```
//Define the date format as per your input
def df = "dd.MM.yyyy HH:mm:ss,S"

//Parse the date string with above date format
def dateTime1 = new Date().parse(df, "13.07.2017 14:03:51,469000000")
def dateTime2 = new Date().parse(df, "13.07.2017 14:03:52,469000000")

//Compare both date times
assert dateTime1 < dateTime2
```